# LocalStorage.getLocalStorage is not a function - JS DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a program where I am storing the data in local storage. Anytime I click on the add/remove button, I keep getting this error. LocalStorage.getLocalStorage is not a function

Below is my Local Storage class

```
class LocalStorage {
  constructor(storageKey) {
    this.storageKey = storageKey;
  }

 getLocalStorage = () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.storageKey));

 setLocalStorage = (data) => localStorage.setItem(this.storageKey, JSON.stringify(data));
}

export default LocalStorage;
```

I'm importing this class in this code block below

```
class SaveAll {
  
save = (title, author) => {
    let books = [];
    if (localStorage.getItem('book') === null) {
      books = [];
    } else {
      // books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('book'));
      books = LocalStorage.getLocalStorage('books');
    }
    const book = { text1: title, text2: author };
    books.push(book);
    // localStorage.setItem('book', JSON.stringify(books));
    LocalStorage.setLocalStorage(books);
  }

}
```

This is the extracted code for the UI

```
static renderBooks = () => {
    bookText.innerHTML = '';
    let books = [];
    if (localStorage.getItem('book') === null) {
      books = [];
    } else {
      books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('book'));

      books.forEach((book) => {
        bookText.innerHTML += `
            <div class="wrapper">
              <p class="book-title">${book.text1}</p>
              <p class="book-author">${book.text2}</p>
              <button onclick="deleteBook('${book.text1}', 
              '${book.text2}')">Remove</button>
            </div>
            `;
      });
    }
  }
```

I have tried implementing the code in the home.html file but it didn't work so I opted to extract them into a separate js files and that is still not working

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to access class methods without class instance so i suggest make your methods static

```
class LocalStorage {
  constructor(storageKey) {
    this.storageKey = storageKey;
  }

 static getLocalStorage = () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.storageKey));

 static setLocalStorage = (data) => localStorage.setItem(this.storageKey, JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

this will solve your problem because static methods are accessible without class instance